# How to create view A closed then view B needs to show using react native?

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native

In my scenario, I am creating single page two views. `View A` and `View B`, Here, I am maintaining two views A and B in a function call with separate render. View A having close button once its clickable enabled  then `View A` needs to hide and `View B` needs to render. How to achieve this?

```
Main Render

RenderMain() {
      return (
        <View>
        ………….
    </View>
        {this.renderViewA()} // Here rendering view A on main view
)
}

View A Function 

renderViewA() {
      return (
        <Overlay>
        …………. // Here rendering View A close click to hide View A and show View B
    </Overlay>
)
}

View B Function

renderViewB() {
      return (
        <Overlay>
        ………….
    </Overlay>
)
}
```

Comment: you can just use a boolean to switch between them and add it to the state

Comment: @youssefali can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

Using a boolean it is very easy to do. Example code:

```
//Create the variable either with useState or state depending on the component
state = {
booleanVariable: true
}

//call your views or functions conditionally
return (
<React.Fragment>
{ booleanVariable && <View A></View A>}

{ !booleanVariable && <View B></View B>}
</React.Fragment>
)
```

In that case you would be rendering View A when booleanVariable is true, and View B when it's false. You can then user your methods to change that variable from true to false.